# How can I only upload from UserForm controls which contain a value?

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I have a user Form through which I am able to upload transactions into a cashflow worksheet. By using cDbl in two controls I am able to ensure that amounts are added to the Worksheet in a format that can be used in calculations. However, by nature these fields are mutually exclusive (Credit & Debit). cDbl requires a value to be populated in each control so I am looking for a method that will check the value of each of the two relevant controls and to ignore them when the value is Null

```vb
Private Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()
'Used to add new transation records to the database

    lastrow = Sheets("Spending Account").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "A").Value = DTPicker1
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "B").Value = cboVendorDetails
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "C").Value = cboTransactionType
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "D").Value = CDbl(Me.txtTransactionAmountDebit)
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "E").Value = CDbl(Me.txtTransactionAmountCredit)
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "F").Value = cboTransactionStatus

With ActiveSheet
    Application.Goto Reference:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-20), Scroll:=True
End With

    Unload Me

    frmRegularTransactions.Show

End Sub
```

I would welcome any solution

Comment: Check the length is non-zero before using CDbl ?

Comment: This would mean that I have to change the code every time I want to upload data. I am looking for fome solution that checks the value of the TextBox and if it is Null, then ignore that line in the code.  Is that possible? In the form only one or other of the two textboxes can be populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Private Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()
    'Used to add new transation records to the database
    Dim r As Long, sCredit As String, sDebit As String
    
    sDebit = Me.txtTransactionAmountDebit
    sCredit = Me.txtTransactionAmountCredit
    
    With Sheets("Spending Account")
        r = 1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(r, "A").Value = DTPicker1
        .Cells(r, "B").Value = cboVendorDetails
        .Cells(r, "C").Value = cboTransactionType
        .Cells(r, "F").Value = cboTransactionStatus
        
        ' credit or debit
        If Len(sDebit) > 0 Then
            If Len(sCredit) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Warning - Both Credit and Debit", vbExclamation
            Else
                .Cells(r, "D").Value = CDbl(sDebit)
            End If
        ElseIf Len(sCredit) > 0 Then
           .Cells(r, "E").Value = CDbl(sCredit)
        End If
          
        If r > 21 Then
            Application.Goto Reference:=.Cells(r - 20, "A"), Scroll:=True
        End If
    End With

    Unload Me
    frmRegularTransactions.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.. This is exactly what I was looking for.. I will save this soemwhere safe for future reference

Comment: For some reason, Excel is now highlighting the cells into wihich currency amounts are added via the user Form with an error that these entries have been entered as Text. This has only started over the weekend and is also affecting a number of files. Any ideas how this can be avoided as I have had to change code in some files to stop this from happening.

Comment: @Denny Not sure why that is but you can set the number format with `.Cells(r, "C").resize(,2).NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"` for accounting